# Parallel.ForEach with ordered input?

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a `Parallel.ForEach()` statement used in my program. It uses a list of some objects as input. I don't care about output order, but I need this loop to take input elements in the same order as in the input list. Is it possible to achieve this with `Parallel.ForEach()`?

Comment: According to the documentation it works with IEnumerable so how could it not take element in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where you need to preserve order from your `IEnumerable<T>`, you'll likely want to [implement a custom partitioner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411.aspx) of the [`OrderablePartitioner<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394988.aspx) variety. The example code for this class includes a simple example which retrieves them one at a time from the enumeration in increasing order.

However, this is a lot of work for something which could be a simple producer-consumer model with something like [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx):

```
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<X>(yourEnumerableOfX);
Action consumer = () =>
{
    X x;
    while (queue.TryDequeue(out x))
    {
        x.Frob();
    }
};

// At most N "in flight"
int maxParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;
var consumers = Enumerable.Repeat(consumer, maxParallelism).ToArray();
Parallel.Invoke(consumers);
```

Using this code you'll be guaranteed First-In-First-Out behavior, and that your requests end up processed "in flight" nearly in the order they are received. Once placed in parallel, you'll have no guarantee they stay in sequential order.

Alternatively, you can use the following (with the restriction that the number of queue items stays fixed):

```
// Executes exactly queue.Count iterations at the time of Parallel.ForEach
// due to "snapshot" isolation of ConcurrentQueue<X>.GetEnumerator()
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<X>(yourEnumerableOfX);
Parallel.ForEach(
    queue,
    _ =>
    {
        X x;
        if (queue.TryDequeue(out x))
        {
            x.Frob();
        }
    });
```

If you would like to keep on producing in one thread, and consuming in others use a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx) with a queue as its backing collection:

```
var queue = new BlockingCollection<X>(new ConcurrentQueue<X>());

// add to it
Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
         foreach (var x in yourEnumerableOfX)
         {
             queue.Add(x);
             Thread.Sleep(200);
         }

         // Signal to our consumers we're done:
         queue.CompleteAdding();
    });
```

Now we need 'unbounded' consumers since we are unsure exactly how many queue items may be present:

```
// Roughly the same consumer code as above, but 'unbounded'
Action consumer = () =>
{
    while (!queue.IsCompleted)
    {
        X x;
        try
        {
            // blocking form, switch to TryTake and maybe Thread.Sleep()
            x = queue.Take();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            // none left
            break;
        }

        x.Frob();
    }
};

int maxParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;
var consumers = Enumerable.Repeat(consumer, maxParallelism).ToArray();
Parallel.Invoke(consumers);
```

Comment: That looks really great, thanks! Just one question, if the `ConcurrentQueue` gets empty then all consumers ends or do they wait till something is added to queue? In my case it would be great to be able to add new items to queue that is being already processed or that is finished.

Comment: They end, but we can switch to `BlockingCollection<T>` and use `bc.CompleteAdding()` to signal when the readers should stop.

Answer (score 2):

This feature cannot exist because the OS scheduler can suspend the execution of item 10 and put item 11 on the CPU core so that 11 executes before 10. No library can counteract that. Any work item can be suspended at any time indefinitely.

You can get **approximate ordering** though. See the other answers for that.

Comment: I didn't think about it from this perspective. But I think the delays from OS scheduler can be milliseconds long at most? This is insignificant in my case because tasks are minutes long and I just want to avoid situation when task added to queue 1 minute ago is processed after the task added 1 hour ago.

Comment: Yes, they are insignificant when tasks are on the order of minutes. Just be aware that you will not see totally strict order. Especially if tasks take very different time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

No, according with documentation all parallel iterator (for and foreach basically) doesn't guarantee any order processing items, it's always unpredictable

Second paraghraph [msdn documentation of parallel loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx)

Comment: But the question is take not process. If it is operating on in IEnumerable then how is it able to take out order? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx

Comment: The take order ins't guarantee. If you pass an IEnumerable to a parallel loop, items are "randomly" taken

Comment: @Blam: for instance it could special case `T[]` or `IList<T>` and pull blocks out in `Parallel.ForEach` (this actually happens). In that case it would *not* necessarily "take" them in strict `IEnumerable<T>` sequential order.

Comment: But according to the documentation is operates on IEnumerable (not IList) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx

Comment: @Blam: it operates on an interface, which does not stop it from special casing on *more derived versions* of this interface. In fact, both vanilla LINQ and PLINQ/TPL provide special cases for other collection interfaces (`Enumerable.Count<T>(x)` where `x` is `IList<T>` is a constant time operation, without special casing this would never be true).

Comment: @user7116 OK, if OP exposed the collection as an IEnumerable then would it be forced to take in order?

Comment: @Blam: you have no guarantees unless you move to a data structure which guarantees First-In-First-Out behavior. Simply using an `IEnumerable<T>` does not provide these guarantees.

Comment: So the partitioner just enumerates whole `IEnumerable<T>` before dispatching tasks?